# Google Api Php Client - Google Auth OAuth 2

Tags: google-oauth, google-api-php-client, google-authentication

My code:

```
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    $obj_token  = json_decode($client->getAccessToken());
    $accessToken = $obj_token->access_token;
    $token_data = $client->verifyIdToken($accessToken)->getAttributes();
}
```

Error:

Uncaught exception 'Google_Auth_Exception' with message 'Wrong number of segments in token: ya29.qQH27NhAXVXPJ64txBjhT_j1FNaVCjosyfwUFKpgsn9LBiyNDS7wgDXVDR31y9hvFbM824mrzOcrWA'

$accessToken should be a string with 2 "." but i don't know why $token_data return a29.qQH27NhAXVXPJ64txBjhT_j1FNaVCjosyfwUFKpgsn9LBiyNDS7wgDXVDR31y9hvFbM824mrzOcrWA', that only have 1 "."

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to verify an `access_token` as an `id_token`. They are different tokens, serving different purposes. For an `id_token` example see the code at https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/idtoken.php, so:

```
$token_data = $client->verifyIdToken()->getAttributes();
```

assuming that an `id_token` was returned by Google as part of the handshake in the first place.

Comment: I'm tried with that example. But the verifyIdToken() method expected a token parameter, so I assumed it was the was the access_token. If you run the example in your localhost whitout parameters in verifyIdToken() you get an Notice: Undefined index: id_token and the same error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Auth_Exception' with message 'Wrong number of segments in token: '

Comment: make sure you get an `id_token` by adding the scope `openid` in the request to the authorization endpoint